# R, debug line number

Tags: debugging, r

When debugging a function (which has been marked debug using `debug("f")`, the debugger gives you the `Browser` prompt which also tells you at what line number in the program you are. If run a couple of test statements at the prompt (to check variables, etc.) the screen scrolls and I no longer know what line number I am at (using SecureCRT so it scrolls past the buffer).  The command `where` only tells you what function you are in.  Does anyone know how to get the actual line number and next statement to be executed?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using `mtrace` in the `debug` package, which pops up a window with the function's source code and highlights the current line.

Comment: does this work remotely? I am running this on a remote terminal using SecureCRT. Will this just use an X-server to pop up a window?

Comment: I'm not sure of the mechanics behind it. Why not give it a shot?

Comment: Do you have access to the source? Why not just step through the function by yourself by invoking `browser()` where you want the function to pause and then just send line by line to R manually.

Answer (score -1):

When I use the regular `browser()`, I set `max.lines` to print to a low number:

> options(deparse.max.lines=100)

so that if the output during debugging is long, I don't have to scroll too far up.